# Solidity : why do many/all implementations of meta-transactions append userAddress at the end of the `addr.call` function?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

After researching forwarder/meta-transaction contracts, I have noticed a lot of implementations are adding the origin EOA address at the end of the signed transaction message.

```
// Append userAddress at the end to extract it from calling context
(bool success, bytes memory returnData) = address(this).call(abi.encodePacked(functionSignature, userAddress));
```

https://github.com/bcnmy/metatx-standard/blob/master/src/contracts/EIP712MetaTransaction.sol#L48

Why is this done? What's the significance?

Answer (score 1):

I am paraphrasing the answer from https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2771

> ### Extracting The Transaction Signer address
>
> The Trusted Forwarder is responsible for calling the Recipient
> contract and MUST append the address of the Transaction Signer (20
> bytes of data) to the end of the call data.
>
> #### For example :
>
> ```
> (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = to.call.value(value)(abi.encodePacked(data, from));
> ```
>
> The Recipient contract can then extract the Transaction Signer address
> by performing 3 operations:
>
> 1. Check that the Forwarder is trusted. How this is implemented is out of the scope of this proposal.
> 2. Extract the Transaction Signer address from the last 20 bytes of the call data and use that as the original sender of the transaction
>    (instead of msg.sender)
> 3. If the msg.sender is not a trusted forwarder (or if the msg.data is shorter than 20 bytes), then return the original msg.sender as it
>    is.
>
> The Recipient MUST check that it trusts the Forwarder to prevent it from extracting address data appended from an untrusted contract. This could result in a forged address.